# Is it possible use several fields to use for similarity in MoreLikeThis while using ContentStreams?

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

Say I'm using MoreLikeThisHandler with an externally supplied text for similarity, which is "potato", and doing the comparison against the fields "title" and "description" of my documents. So I would have a URL like this:

http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/mlt?stream.body=potato&mlt.fl=title,description

Checking the results with `&mlt.interestingTerms=details` I find that only the first specified field, "title", is being used for extracting the interestingTerms. Changing the order of the specified fields in the URL gives that still the first field is being used for the mlt matching, "description". This behavior doesn't change when suppling text of several words.

Is it really possible to use more than one field for this, given that there are examples in the Solr Wiki that also shows two fields for the mlt similarity querying using ContentStreams? ("manu" and "cat" fields, https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler)

I already have `enableRemoteStreaming="true"`.

(In reality I'm not posting text to the stream body to get similar documents, but streaming a document from a URL using `stream.url`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation in versions of Solr before 7.4  It was fixed in 7.4 and should be possible with that version or newer.  For more information see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5351